# Check if dictionary key is filled with list of 2 numbers

Tags: python

I have a dictionary:

```
self.currently_occupied = {obj:[0, 0]}
```

I need to check if the value of obj contains anything other than two numbers in a list

Example:

```
obj:[58, -234]  is ok
obj:[32]        is not 
obj:[]          is not
obj:[4, k]      is not
```

Comment: Does it matter if they are floats or ints?

Comment: Does it have to be a list object, or would any iterable work?

Comment: Do you also want to test that the numbers are in a list, or is the existence of the list a given? (Just asking because it would add one more test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to large extent based on @Levon's solution, but I am adding one more detail. Just using is `isinstance` can lead some lists that are not composed of numbers to qualify. For example:

```
[float('nan'), float('inf')]
```

would qualify because technically both above values are `float`; however, they are not numbers; therefore we need to add an additional condition to control for that.

```
import numpy as np

def check(x):
    if isinstance(x,list):
        if len(x) == 2:
            if all(isinstance(ele, (int, float)) and np.isinf(ele) == False and np.isnan(ele) == False for ele in x):
                return True
    return False
```

Result:

```
>>> check([2,3])
True
>>> check([4, float('inf')])
False
```

EDIT:

I think the use of `isfinite` makes the code cleaner, and I also think that we don't need to use `isinstance` in this case. The resulting code would be:

```
def check(x):
    if isinstance(x,list):
        if len(x) == 2:
            if all(np.isfinite(ele) for ele in x):
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this test:

```
(len(d[obj]) == 2) and isinstance(d[obj][0], int) and isinstance(d[obj][1], int)
```

`isinstance(d[obj][1], (float, int))` will check for *both* `int` and `float`, and `long` could be added too.

This demonstrates what needs to be tested and how to meet the OP request, though the test could be shortened in various ways with clever syntax no doubt.

UPDATE: As noted/suggested by @Akavall, in case the test needs to include that this is a list, the following could be prepended with an `and` to the test above:

```
isinstance(d[obj], list)
```

Comment: it should be `isinstance` not `isintance`

Comment: And to think I once told a teacher: "I want to be an engineer, not a compiler!"

Comment: It seems that OP also wants the numbers in a list, so it might be worth it to add this condition. `isinstance(d[obj], list)`. And btw, I didn't downvote your post :), just making a comment.

Comment: @Akavall ah .. thanks I appreciate your comment. I guess that would be one way to read the spec. I'll update my answer to include this, but it's just guessing that this is the perceived problem. A downvote without an explanation isn't really helpful to anyone.

Comment: +1 for the bizarre -1. :P This is certainly a valid way to do it, I guess the -1 was probably for not checking explicitly for a list object.

Comment: @alpha123 apparently not .. the downvote's still there .. doesn't matter as its pointless w/o an explanation. Hopefully this meets the OPs requirements

Answer (score 1):

Let's quickly see how that can be achieved in nice python:

```
def foo(currently_occupied):
    return all(isinstance(item, list)
               and len(item) == 2
               and all (isinstance(subitem, int)
                        for subitem in item)
               for item in currently_occupied.itervalues())
```

Now, let me tell you that you're not supposed to implement this kind of check in Python. The philosophy here is *duck typing*: if it walks like a duck, and sounds like a duck, well it's a duck.

You don't ask the object if it's a list and has two integers. You index it as if it were a list, you take the first element and use it as an integer. If anything fails, gee, not your fault, the caller's fault.

At most, you could try/catch type errors and rethrow them with a more descriptive message, but don't go verifying everything's type.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def two_int_list(value):
    return isinstance(value, list) and len(value) == 2 and \
           all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), value))

def validate_dict_key(dictionary, key, valid=two_int_list):
    return key in dictionary and valid(dictionary[key])

validate_dict_key({'obj': [58, -234]}, 'obj')  # True
validate_dict_key({'obj': [32]}, 'obj')        # False
validate_dict_key({'obj': (58, -234)}, 'obj')  # False; only accepts list objects, not sure if this is what you want
```